# python 3.4 UTF 8 string on list element

Tags: python, utf-8, python-3.4, unicode-string

I will insert this codes to my program but it gives me syntax unicode error because of the Turkish letters. How can I solve this? I cant find any solution on python 3.4

```
bilissel_olay = [
    "Dikkatini çeken nesne/durum/olayı ayrıntılarıyla açıklayabiliyor ve sorular sorabiliyor.",
    "Dikkatini çeken nesne/durum/olaya yönelik sorular sorabiliyor.",
    "Dikkatini çeken nesne/durum/olaya yönelik sorular sormada ve açıklamada desteğe ihtiyacı var.",
    "Dikkatini çeken nesne/durum/olaya yönelik sorular sormada ve açıklamada başarısız."]
bilissel_sayi = [
    "İleriye doğru birer birer ritmik sayabiliyor. Saydığı nesnelerin kaç tane olduğunu söyleyebiliyor ve rakamları tanıyabiliyor.",
    "Saydığı nesnelerin kaç tane olduğunu söyleyebiliyor ve rakamları tanıyabiliyor.",
    "Rakamları tanımakta ve saydığı nesnelerin kaç tane olduğunu söylemekte zorlanıyor."]

bilissel_siniflandirma = [
    "Nesne veya varlıkları çeşitli özelliklerine göre gözlemleyebiliyor, eşleştirebiliyor ve gruplayabiliyor.",
    "Nesne/varlıkları yapıldığı malzemeye göre gruplayabiliyor. Nesne/varlıkları büyüklüklerine göre sıralayabiliyor.",
    "Nesne veya varlıkların tanınmasında desteklenmeli.",
    "Nesne veya varlıkları tanımakta zorluk çekiyor."]

print (bilissel_sayi[0])
```

I get the exception:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 0: unexpected end of data – Melih Muhammet Gundogdu 10 hours ago
```

Comment: try adding # coding=utf-8 to the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on python3, the default encoding should be utf-8, so you should not need to specify it explictly.
If you're on python2, place the following in the header of your code:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for reference.

Comment: I m using python 3.4 with visual studio 2014. I tried both your and @mchackam 's codes but still the same error. 

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Comment: @MelihMuhammetGundogdu Make sure the file is actually UTF-8 encoded, when adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. Either change the encoding to match or change the the coding signiture to match the encoding.